# I am trying to split contents of an excel spreadsheet cell

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to split the contents of a cell from an excel spreadsheet, being new to Python, I can't quite figure out the syntax for it.  I am using the `xlrd` and `xlwt` libraries.  So far I can get the correct columns I need and would like to split out the contents of the cell `pvalue` similar to the excel function `text to columns`, is this a practical thing to do in python? Everything I can find on line, already has data neatly formatted with all data points in a seperate column, I was wondering if I could get a point in the right direction.  Here is the code I have so far

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

# open and create workbook
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myexcelfile.xlsx')
workbookwrite = xlwt.Workbook('output.xlsx')

# open and create sheets
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet = workbookwrite.add_sheet('Sheet1')

i = 1

# iterate through rows in worksheet, get columns completed_at and name
for rows in range(worksheet.nrows):
   cell1 = worksheet.cell(rows, 3).value
   cell2 = worksheet.cell(rows, 15).value
   row = sheet.row(i)

# if a completed_at date is empty, don't write data to new workbook
    if cell1 != '':
       value = cell2
       pvalue = cell2.split(',')
       row.write(0, cell1)
       row.write(1, pvalue)
   i += 1

workbookwrite.save('output.xls')
```

If I could get direction on a different library to use, if there is a better one out there that would be great.  Thanks

Comment: If you print `cell2` and `pvalue`, what do you see, and what do you want to see?

Comment: Oh I think I understand... So `pvalue` is a list of items that were comma-separated in `cell2`, and you want to write each element of `pvalue` into its own column starting at column 1?  If so, just do a `for` loop like this:  `for col, element in enumerate(pvalue): row.write(col+1, element)`

Comment: Thanks Tim Johns, that did it, if you could make your comment an answer I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pvalue` is a list of items that were comma-separated in `cell2`, and you want to write each element of `pvalue` into its own column starting at column 1.  To do so, just do a `for` loop like this:

```
for col, element in enumerate(pvalue):
    row.write(col+1, element)
```